# Can a SpannableString be set in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, spannablestring

If a SpannableString can be set as the arguments of a fragment how is it done?

```
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(PagesFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, Page[position]);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
```

What needs to be changed in this sample code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As SpannableString implements CharSequence you can use putCharSequence method.

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putCharSequence(PagesFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, Page[position]);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
```

Regards.